# How can I set size and location of the app window within a ui-test?

Tags: swift, cocoa, frame, xcuitest

A bit of background: I recently implemented a Drag and Drop Behavior to my app, where I can drag items from e.g. the Finder inside my NSTableView. Now I wanted to write a few ui-tests for this new functionality.

The general idea was to move the finder window to the left side of the screen and my application window to the right side of the screen and then execute the drag and drop. The drag and drop itself is not the problem, the problem is the setup of the mentioned window layout. I cannot find a convenient way to resize and move the two windows. Coming from .net, I expected something like `app.window.setSize(..)` or `app.window.moveTo(...)`.

What I tried so far:

- As I have **Magnet** installed on my Mac, I tried the easy way out and sent key-events (*control* + *option* + *arrow*) to the window. This did not work, sending the keystrokes results in an error beep. Doing this manually during the tests works, so I don't know what exactly stops Magnet from rearranging the windows, but I guess it has something to do with the Testing Framework. I did not dig deeper into this, as it would have been a cheap solution anyway.
- Drag the app window corners based on screen dimensions, e.g. for the window on the left I drag the corners to the top left, bottom left, top middle and bottom middle of the screen. This requires that all four corners are visible on screen, but that's a problem for another day. The solution would normally work, but the problem is that the y-coordinates I get from the frame of my app window are not what I was expecting. I do receive the location of the app window with `app.windows.firstMatch.frame.origin`. The x-coordinates look alright, but the y-coordinates are totally off (from what I expected).

I can't find many resources regarding the `origin` or `frame` members. Any idea on how to face this problem or where to find a documentation about the XCUITest-Framework and the basic concepts behind it? The [official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cgrect/1454354-origin) doesn't help in this case. I only found [this short explanation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/Devpedia-CocoaApp/CoordinateSystem.html) in the apple documentation archive about the coordinate system of macOS (or OS X back then) applications.

Comment: Have you ever figured out how to change the size of the window on OSX?